# Flatlist header and footer rendering unnecessary in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in react native and developing a mobile application in React-Native.

At one screen I have used Flatlist to show number of video items, and there is one header and footer also required in that particular scree. The thing is working well but when I put console in header and footer component then I got to know that these component are re-rendring number of time. So ho can I restrict them to re-render. I have used various way to handle but nothing get help me.

Here is the code of my screen where I am using this thing.

```
return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.videosView}>
        <FlatList
          windowSize={6}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          numColumns={2}
          data={pozzles?.length % 2 === 0 ? pozzles : [...pozzles, {}]}
          ListHeaderComponent={userInfoHeader}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          ListFooterComponent={videoListFooter}
          columnWrapperStyle={styles.coloumContainer}
          style={styles.videoListStyle}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.videoListContentStyle}
          ListFooterComponentStyle={{ backgroundColor: Colors.GRAYOFF }}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          onEndReached={onEndReachCall}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

And here is the header and footer component :-

```
function userInfoHeader() {
    console.log('Header rendring.....');
    return (
      <VStack justify="space-evenly" style={styles.editView}>
        <HStack style={styles.userSummary}>
          <Image
            style={styles.userImage}
            source={{
              uri:
                user?.user?.profilePhoto !== ''
                  ? user?.user?.profilePhoto
                  : pozzlePilot,
            }}
            height={112}
            width={112}
          />
         ............
        </HStack> 
    </VStack>
   }
  )
```

Footer :-

```
function videoListFooter() {
        console.log('Footer rendring.....');
        return (
         <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
         {user?.user?.pozzleVideos === 0 ? (
           <>{noVideoYetLabel()}</>
             ............
         </View > 
       }
      )
```

Can someone please help me to restrict that re-rendring....

Comment: Did you had any luck finding a solution?